# Вернуть кортеж после PUT MySQL C#

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqlconnector

В рамках собственного проекта работаю с БД на MySQL через C#. С помощью коннектора оперирую чистыми запросами, передавая их как строку. Идентификаторами кортежей (первичными ключами) управляет сама база (`auto_increment`). Обычный код по добавлению у меня выглядит так:

```
public void PutPet()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PatientID)
        || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Alias)
        || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Form))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    string CommandText =
        "insert into " + TABLE_NAME + 
        "(" + ATRIBUTE_PATIENT_ID + 
        ", " + ATRIBUTE_ALIAS + 
        ", " + ATRIBUTE_FORM + 
        ", " + ATRIBUTE_MF + 
        ", " + ATRIBUTE_BORN_DATE + 
        ", " + ATRIBUTE_STATUS + 
        ") values('" + PatientID + 
        "','" + Alias + 
        "','" + Form + 
        "','" + MF + 
        "','" + BornDate + 
        "','" + Status + "')";//команда

    MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(DataBaseManager.GetConnectLine());//создаем объект для подключения
    MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(CommandText, myConnection);//создаем объект передачи команды

    myConnection.Open();//открываем подключение

    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();//передаем команду

    myConnection.Close();//закрываем подключение

}
```

Однако метод `ExecuteNonQuery()` возвращает только число затронутых строк. Какой метод мне использовать, чтобы добавить и получить объект, добавленный в БД, со сгенерированным идентификатором? И есть-ли такой метод вообще?

Comment: Если будете использовать EF - то после `SaveChanges` у всех вставленных сущностей свойство `Id` обновится автоматически

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел не совсем стройное решение проблемы. У класса MySqlCommand есть свойство LastInsertedId, содержащее long значение идентификатора последнего добавленного ключа в текущей транзакции. Тем не менее, приходится делать отдельный запрос на сервер, хоть и без повторного установления соединения.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы получить последнее значение `id` при автоинкременте обычно используется `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Например:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Но...
Как такая система будет вести себя в многопользовательской среде? Вопрос риторический.

Можно попробовать поработать с [транзакциями](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html). Только более разумно поработать со структурой таблицы (например, вместо автоинкрементного `id` генерировать GUID перед добавлением) или как сказали ранее в комментариях, используйте ORM.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что моя система многопользовательская

Comment: Можно попробовать поиграться с транзакциями. Но более разумно поработать со структурой таблицы (например, вместо автоинкрементного `id` генерировать GUID перед добавлением) или как сказали ранее в комментариях, используйте ORM.

Comment: я пишу свою библиотеку для работы с MySQL для этого проекта. знаю, неоправданно трудоемко, но так и надо - это же диплом. поэтому ORM отпадает. можете подробнее рассказать про транзакции?

Comment: Транзакции тема весьма обширная. Материалы по ним, тем более применительно к конкретной задаче, проще посмотреть самостоятельно в документации (ссылку добавил в ответ) и в статьях на эту тему на профильных ресурсах.